# change input hidden controls in ruby mechanize

Tags: ruby, ajax, nokogiri, mechanize

When I click on a button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.lista_de_precios.opcion.value='por_categoria';showCat()" value="Por Categoría" class="btn btn-mini">
```

A input type:hidden value is changed to the button name: "por_categoria"

How do I change

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="opcion">
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" value="por_categoria" name="opcion">
```

in Ruby Mechanize gem, I already tried using python examples in ruby with no success..

```
page.form.new_control('hidden','opcion',{'value': 'por_categoria'}
```

**Update:**

I investigated a little bit more and:

**QUOTE from [webpage](http://toddhayton.com/2014/12/08/form-handling-with-mechanize-and-beautifulsoup/)**

> Sometimes mechanize won't pick up certain hidden form controls. Since mechanize doesn't pick up these controls, you will need to create them manually in order to get the form submission to work.

I think I will leave this post as is, because I don't know how to create form controls in this ruby code and mechanize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the advice on that page, it's talking about Python mechanize which is a different library (and not a very good one apparently!)

Here's how to do it with ruby mechanize:

```
form = page.forms[0] # or some other number
form['opcion']  = 'por_categoria'
```